# iOS 12 and SceneKit: Node showing up in White

Tags: scenekit, ios12

The application we had have been using SceneKit for a while and never had any issues with it until recently. Compared to earlier, now the render doesnt show the node in there actual color. Please see the images attached for more detail. If anyone has a solution to it then I would highly appreciate it.

iOS 12
https://image.ibb.co/i9sVGp/PNG_image.png

iOS 11
https://image.ibb.co/bBRCU9/IMG_0145.png

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem in an app that downloads OBJ and MTL files with their texture images and renders them. All image texture materials were just blank white.

In my case, the problem was solved by manually disabling the emission property on the model's materials:

```
    for (id object in self.modelNode.geometry.materials) {
        ((SCNMaterial*)object).emission.contents = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

I have no clue why the emission component was set at all and why this changed with iOS 12/13.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. Was trying to load .obj with .mtl and some textures, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the 'Emission' property from white to black under the material settings in xcode. Save the file as a scene-kit file to avoid having to deal with it

- Select the model
- Go to the panel on the right

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issues for the moment by choosing OpenGL ES as render mode:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Stefan, doesnt seem to work when I try that.I have the same output as before. Although I get this error this time around not sure how useful it is:
`Physically based lighting model is not supported by the OpenGL renderer, using Phong instead`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by setting the following properties:

```
self.scnView.pointOfView.camera.wantsHDR = true
self.scnView.pointOfView.camera.minimumExposure = -1
self.scnView.pointOfView.camera.maximumExposure = -1
```

Apart from these properties, you can also set
emission and lightingmodel geometry properties of your node.